# How can I run XAMPP on startup in Windows?

Tags: php, html, xampp

I am using Windows 7 and xampplite 1.7.3.

One of my research gives me idea that I need to start automatically the "APACHE2" on services.msc. But when I go to my services there is no Apache2 there, no apache service at all. Please help me how to start xampp automatically as my PC gets ON.

Comment: Did you check the "services" box next to Apache in the XAMPP control panel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you check the svc box on XAMPP control panel the service should start automaticly.